# Change your home directory in vim

Tags: vim

I have changed the registry settings so that the user's folder is not saved in `C:` but in `E:`. Everything is working fine except for Vim (and Cygwin, but I don't want it now).

Whenever I launch Vim, it automatically creates a new folder `C:\Users\Administrator` and starts saving its files there.

That's because `$HOME` is `C:\Users\Administrator`. I want it to change so that it can point to my custom location.

Comment: Same problem here, and I can't change $HOME as it was set by my development environment to a read-only net drive :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Vim should set $HOME to ${HOMEDRIVE}${HOMEPATH} unless you already have %HOME% set to something else in the Windows environment.

If you start a Command Prompt, and run:

```
set | findstr /R "^HOME"
```

I think you should see

```
HOMEDRIVE=E:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Administrator
```

I suspect that either the HOMEDRIVE is still set to C: (your change of Users folder didn't take) or there's a setting there for HOME too.

Comment: use `%USERPROFILE%` as the variable ...

Comment: %USERPROFILE% does not necessarily have the same value: domain users with a remote profile, for example.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Examples_from_Microsoft_Windows .. "Its value is the location of the current user's profile directory" ... looks ok for me.

Comment: This is my output if I run the command:
HOME=C:\Users\Administrator
HOMEDRIVE=E:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Abdulsattar

Comment: I changed the HOME environment variable and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Setting a HOME environment variable which didn't exist on my Win 7 machine did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could set the environment variable `VIMINIT` to `source E:/Users/Administrator/vimrc`. Then in that `vimrc` file you'll need to set the 'runtimepath' option to an appropriate value to find all your plugins. See

```
:help VIMINIT
:help 'runtimepath'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change $HOME, try creating two new system environment variables:

$VIM: the directory you want to put vimrc and use as vimfiles

$VIMRUNTIME: the directory you install Vim (for example: E:\Program_Files\Vim\vim82)